# How to put shapes (oval, rectangle, line) in VisualBasic tableLayoutPanel?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Sounds like a silly problem, but whenever I drag an oval to the table, an error pops out: "Cannot create component of type 'Shape' in container of type 'TableLayoutPanel'. Is there a way I can work around this?

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate on what your actual goal is (specifics aside) i.e. I'm trying to make a UI with X to show Y. Screenshots would help.

Answer (score 1):

The Shape classes require a *container*, an instance of the ShapeContainer class, pretty invisible when you use the designer to drop shapes on a form.  Technically you can find it back from the control selector combobox at the top of the Properties window, the default name is "shapeContainer1" and has no properties at all.  The surface of this container class is used to draw the shapes.

All of this is done completely automatically with a custom designer, it ensures that the ShapeContainer instance is created when you drag a shape from the toolbox onto the form.  Problem is, this designer isn't quite smart enough to deal with the TableLayoutPanel class.  What it *should* do is create a ShapeContainer that can be embedded in a cell of the TLP, it doesn't.  Instead it just gives up and displays the message box.  Or to put it another way, you are seeing the Microsoft programmer having given up on making this work.  It is not very simple to do correctly, pretty hard to get rid of those otherwise invisible containers again.

Only workaround you have is to write the code yourself.  You do so in the constructor of the form.  A simple example that puts a LineShape in the upper/left table cell:

```
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        var line = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.LineShape() {
            X1 = 0, Y1 = 0, X2 = 50, Y2 = 20
        };
        var container = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.ShapeContainer();
        container.Shapes.Add(line);
        container.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 20);
        tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(container, 0, 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread... but for the sake of someone who might be looking into an easier option in the future this is the solution I found:

Insert a **Panel** inside of your **TablePanelLayout** where you want to place a shape and VisualStudio should allow you to place the shape inside the newly created panel.

Good luck.